# Replacing data.frame column with IDs with Column with corresponding names taken from another data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame `df1` that looks like this:

```
id          name     type                                           
46        hsa:4052    gene 
50        hsa:7057    gene 
52        hsa:8454    gene
```

And then I have a second data frame `df2` that looks like this:

```
entry1    entry2      type       name        value
46         44        PPrel      activation    -->
52         50        PPrel      activation    -->
29         27        PPrel      activation    -->
```

Now the common columns in the two data frames are id from `df1` and `entry1` and `entry2` from `df2`. What i want my results to look like is this:

```
entry1    entry2      type       name        value
hsa:4052   44        PPrel      activation    -->
hsa:8454  hsa:7057   PPrel      activation    -->
29         27        PPrel      activation    -->
```

So what i want basically is replace the `entry1` and `entry2` `id`s in `df2` with the names of corresponding ids from `df1`. I tried merge but obviously merge doesn't help here. Any help?

Comment: Merge works, we just need to merge twice, once on entry1, then on entry2.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df2[,1:2]<-lapply(df2[,1:2],
           function(x) ifelse(x %in% df1$id,df1$name[match(x,df1$id)],x))
#    entry1   entry2  type       name value
#1 hsa:4052       44 PPrel activation   -->
#2 hsa:8454 hsa:7057 PPrel activation   -->
#3       29       27 PPrel activation   -->
```

Comment: I am sorry @nicola but its not working, the values of entry1 and entry2  in df2 are changed but are not the names from df1

Comment: Make sure that df1$name is set as.character(), i.e. try: df1$name<-as.character(df1$name)